# OSM : More nodes in a way than defined nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Using OverPass I am requesting all the ways and nodes in a specific area.

The documentation says : "The nodes defining the geometry of the way are enumerated in the correct order, and indicated only by reference using their unique identifier. These nodes must have been already defined separately with their coordinates."

But in the result I get, the definitions of some nodes are missing, as I get some nodes ID child of a way that I can't find in the nodes definition.

Here is my OverPass QL query :

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
node;
<;
);
out;
```

I am missing something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't request all "ways and nodes". Instead it just requests nodes and performs a "recurse up" to get ways these nodes are part of. However for these ways you will only obtain the nodes from your initial query. You will need an additional "recurse down" to query for all other nodes these ways consist of:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
node;
<;
);
out body;
>;
out;
```

Example: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/FGj

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my query ! But what I don't understand is why the nodes we get by recursing down are not already there when we request the nodes. Are nodes composing ways not treated as standard nodes ?

Comment: Did you mean recurse up instead of recurse down? Your query essentially asks for "all nodes in the current bounding box and all ways which contain these nodes". However these ways do consist of more than just the nodes from the current bounding box. To obtain these additional nodes outside of the bounding box you need an additional recurse down step.

Comment: Oh ok Ils understand. So if I need only the ways AND all the nodes INSIDE these ways the query would be :

Comment: A way is a two-dimensional object. There is no "inside". Did you mean ways and all nodes these ways consist of? In this case just query for the ways and perform a recurse down:

`[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
way;
);
out body;
>;
out;`. Also see the [Overpass API Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide), it has many examples.

Comment: Thank you, that was what i was looking for. By inside I was meaning child objet (nodes) of a way parent. I already looked at thé exemples but I think they are way too specific and complicated. Couldn't find the simple exemple of geting all the nodes. Anyway I will try this query and see if I get all the nodes I want. Thank you very much for your Time !

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, a solution based on the `<` (recurse up) statement does not meet your requirements. To find out why, we take a look a the [Overpass QL documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_up_.28.3C.29):

> The recurse up standalone query is written as a single less than symbol, "<".
>
> It takes an input set. It produces a result set. Its result set is
>   composed of:
>
> - all ways that have a node which appears in the input set; plus
> - **all relations that have a node** or way **which appears in the input set**; plus
> - all relations that have a way which appears in the result set

You will notice that your query also returns many relations, although in your question you mentioned you wanted only nodes and ways in your result.

A correct query would look as follows. Instead of using `<`, we're explicitly telling in QL that we only want ways for a set of nodes, and again, all nodes for a set of ways - and nothing else!

```
(
  node({{bbox}});
  way(bn);
  node(w);
);
out meta;
```

*(Btw: please forget about the Overpass language guide mentioned above. It is incomplete and not maintained at the moment).*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am searching for all the ways and ONLY the nodes that are part of the way. How could I do that ?